# How do I install Dotfuscator in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, dotfuscator

I'm currently using MacOS for my C# development environment, and have been pretty satisfied with the packages available. However, since my codebase is proprietary, my coworkers recommended that I obfuscate the code using Dotfuscator. I've gone over the Microsoft documentation for direct installation to Visual Studio, but I think it may only apply to Windows. Does anyone know how to install Dotfuscator on Visual Studio for Mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Update: Dotfuscator [now has Mac support](https://www.preemptive.com/blog/article/1175-dotfuscator-6-0-beta-entering-the-next-era-of-dotfuscator/90-dotfuscator); the MSBuild components can be installed via NuGet and referenced from VS for Mac via [the same instructions as Windows](https://www.preemptive.com/dotfuscator/pro/6.0/userguide/en/getting_started_protect.html).

I work for PreEmptive Solutions, who make Dotfuscator. Dotfuscator is not currently able to be installed on a Mac. We do have alternative solutions for Xamarin builds (Android and/or iOS), and we are working on cross-platform solutions in general. We do plan to make Dotfuscator available for Mac users, but I don't have a date for that yet.

What types of apps are you building? That will help us provide a more-detailed answer, and/or we can update this answer as the situation changes in the future.

Comment: Hi Nathan, do you have an update on the status of the Dotfuscator porting to Visual Studio fo Mac? I'm developing an android/ios app with xamarin and dotfuscator could be very helpful to me! Thanks!

Comment: @DSoldo, I still don't have a firm date for shipping it, but we are committed to doing it The planning work has already begun, with implementation soon to follow. In the meantime, though, we have multiple ways that Xamarin iOS developers can use Dotfuscator (if you have some way to have a Windows machine). If that's at all interesting to you, please reach out to sales or support. Our Xamarin support (on Windows) is very effective and quite easy to integrate.

Comment: I'd be using Dotfuscator for penetration testing. I figured out how to use it on Windows, but I'd prefer to use it on a Unix-based OS. The apps would be pretty simple, either scripts or very small applications.

Comment: @NathanArthur any plans of having VS for Mac support on community edition ?

Comment: @giorgos we've announced that we're planning support (see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/dotfuscator-pro-6-mac-support/) but haven't set a date.